# Custom Header | Match Table of Contents Font Size with Fancy Header Font Size

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, fancyhdr

### Background

I am creating a maths primer worksheet. I just need help with `fancyhdr` under `% [ pkg - page format ]`  and `\tableofcontents` under `% [ document ]`. Here is an example:

```
% [ file: maths-primer.tex ] =======================================================================

% [ pkg - document format ] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
\documentclass[11pt, table, dvipsnames]{extarticle}
\usepackage{extsizes, advdate}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}


% [ pkg - page format ] ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{titling, titlesec, fancyhdr}
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    total={2.54cm,25.7cm}, 
    textwidth=14.3cm,
    top=4cm,
    bottom=4cm
}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\filcenter\scshape\normalsize}{}{1pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\filcenter\scshape\LARGE}{}{1pt}{}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\thepage \ \textbar \quad \textsc{Maths Primer}}
\fancyhead[R]{\scshape\leftmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

% [ pkg - maths presentation ] ---------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, array, calc, thmtools, bm, mathtools}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2em}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

% [ pkg - graphics presentation ] ------------------------------------------------------------------
\definecolor{paleGB}{HTML}{F6F8FA}
\definecolor{darkGB}{HTML}{E9EEF3



% [ document ] -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\color{black!88}
\renewcommand*{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Remove paragraph indentation
\begingroup
\footnotesize

% [title] block ...
% -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------[S]
\begin{center}
    \rmfamily
    \Large{\textsc{Maths Primer}}
    {\fontsize{9pt}{10pt}\selectfont \tableofcontents}
\end{center}
% -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------[E]
\newpage


% section: Deterministic Maths /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
\rmfamily
\section{Deterministic Maths}
\subsection{Arithmetic: Fundamentals}
\noindent
\textbf{Essence:} \blindtext
% ////// [ PARAGRAPH END ]

\newpage
% section: [ geometry ]
\rmfamily
\subsection{Geometry: Fundamentals}
\noindent
\textbf{Essence:} \blindtext
% ////// [ PARAGRAPH END ]

\newpage
\rmfamily
\subsection{Geometry: Trigonometry}
\noindent
\textbf{Essence:} \blindtext
% ////// [ PARAGRAPH END ]

\newpage
\rmfamily
\subsection{Geometry: Plane-Analytic Geometry}
\noindent
\textbf{Essence:} \blindtext
% ////// [ PARAGRAPH END ]

\newpage
\rmfamily
\subsection{Geometry: Solid-Analytic Geometry}
\noindent
\textbf{Essence:} \blindtext
% ////// [ PARAGRAPH END ]

\newpage
% section: [ algebra ]
\rmfamily
\subsection{Algebra: Time Algebra}
\noindent
\textbf{Essence:} \blindtext
% ////// [ PARAGRAPH END ]

\newpage
\rmfamily
\subsection{Algebra: Linear Algebra}
\noindent
\textbf{Essence:} \blindtext
% ////// [ PARAGRAPH END ]

\newpage
\rmfamily
\subsection{Algebra: Space Algebra}
\noindent
\textbf{Essence:} \blindtext
% ////// [ PARAGRAPH END ]

\newpage
% section: [ mathematical analysis ]
\rmfamily
\subsection{Mathematical Analysis: Fundamentals}
\noindent
\textbf{Essence:} \blindtext
% ////// [ PARAGRAPH END ]

\newpage
\rmfamily
\subsection{Mathematical Analysis: Differential Calculus}
\noindent
\textbf{Essence:} \blindtext
% ////// [ PARAGRAPH END ]

\newpage
\rmfamily
\subsection{Mathematical Analysis: Integral Calculus}
\noindent
\textbf{Essence:} \blintext
% ////// [ PARAGRAPH END ]

\newpage
\rmfamily
\subsection{Mathematical Analysis: Series}
\noindent
\textbf{Essence:} \blindtext
% ////// [ PARAGRAPH END ]

\newpage
\rmfamily
\subsection{Mathematical Analysis: Differential Equations}
\noindent
\textbf{Essence:} \blindtext
% ////// [ PARAGRAPH END ]


\newpage
% section: Foundational Maths //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
\rmfamily
\section{Foundational Maths}
\subsection{major: minor}
\noindent
\textbf{Essence:} \blindtext
% ////// [ PARAGRAPH END ]


\newpage
% section: Stochastic Maths ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
\rmfamily
\section{Stochastic Maths}
\subsection{major: minor}
\noindent
\textbf{Essence:} \blindtext
% ////// [ PARAGRAPH END ]


\newpage
% section: Discrete Maths //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
\rmfamily
\section{Discrete Maths}
\subsection{major: minor}
\noindent
\textbf{Essence:} \blindtext
% ////// [ PARAGRAPH END ]

\endgroup
\end{document}
```

---

### Issue

When the TOC title appears on the top-right side of my document header its font size does not match the font size on the left side of the header, specified by the `fancyhead` preamble. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is to get rid of the uppercase letters in the right header with

```
\fancyhead[R]{\scshape\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

`\tableofcontents` is defined like this within [`extarticle.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/extsizes/extarticle.cls):

```
\newcommand\tableofcontents{%
  \section*{\contentsname
    \@mkboth{%
      \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}%
  \@starttoc{toc}%
}
```

It sets a unnumbered `\section`, with the headings set using `\MakeUppercase`. Redefine it to use `\textsc` instead (or patch it using [`etoolbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)):

[image]

```
% [ file: maths-primer.tex ] =======================================================================

% [ pkg - document format ] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
\documentclass[11pt, table, dvipsnames]{extarticle}
\usepackage{extsizes, advdate}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter
% Update ToC to use \textsc in header, not \MakeUppercase
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{%
  \section*{%
    \contentsname
    \@mkboth{\textsc{\contentsname}}{\textsc{\contentsname}}%'
  }
  \@starttoc{toc}%
}
\makeatother

% [ pkg - page format ] ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{geometry, xcolor}
\usepackage{titling, titlesec, fancyhdr}
\geometry{
  a4paper,
  total={2.54cm,25.7cm}, 
  textwidth=14.3cm,
  top=4cm,
  bottom=4cm
}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\filcenter\scshape\normalsize}{}{1pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\filcenter\scshape\LARGE}{}{1pt}{}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}


\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\thepage \ \textbar \quad \textsc{Maths Primer}}
\fancyhead[R]{\scshape\leftmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

% [ pkg - maths presentation ] ---------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, array, calc, thmtools, bm, mathtools}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2em}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

% [ pkg - graphics presentation ] ------------------------------------------------------------------
\definecolor{paleGB}{HTML}{F6F8FA}
\definecolor{darkGB}{HTML}{E9EEF3}



% [ document ] -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\color{black!88}
\renewcommand*{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Remove paragraph indentation
\begingroup
\footnotesize

% [title] block ...
% -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------[S]
\begin{center}
  \rmfamily
  \show\tableofcontents
  \Large{\textsc{Maths Primer}}
  {\fontsize{9pt}{10pt}\selectfont \tableofcontents}
\end{center}
% -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------[E]
\newpage


% section: Deterministic Maths /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
\rmfamily
\section{Deterministic Maths}
\subsection{Arithmetic: Fundamentals}
\noindent
\textbf{Essence:} \blindtext
% ////// [ PARAGRAPH END ]

\newpage
% section: [ geometry ]
\rmfamily
\subsection{Geometry: Fundamentals}
\noindent
\textbf{Essence:} \blindtext
% ////// [ PARAGRAPH END ]

\newpage
\rmfamily
\subsection{Geometry: Trigonometry}
\noindent
\textbf{Essence:} \blindtext
% ////// [ PARAGRAPH END ]

\newpage
\rmfamily
\subsection{Geometry: Plane-Analytic Geometry}
\noindent
\textbf{Essence:} \blindtext
% ////// [ PARAGRAPH END ]

\newpage
\rmfamily
\subsection{Geometry: Solid-Analytic Geometry}
\noindent
\textbf{Essence:} \blindtext
% ////// [ PARAGRAPH END ]

\newpage
% section: [ algebra ]
\rmfamily
\subsection{Algebra: Time Algebra}
\noindent
\textbf{Essence:} \blindtext
% ////// [ PARAGRAPH END ]

\newpage
\rmfamily
\subsection{Algebra: Linear Algebra}
\noindent
\textbf{Essence:} \blindtext
% ////// [ PARAGRAPH END ]

\newpage
\rmfamily
\subsection{Algebra: Space Algebra}
\noindent
\textbf{Essence:} \blindtext
% ////// [ PARAGRAPH END ]

\newpage
% section: [ mathematical analysis ]
\rmfamily
\subsection{Mathematical Analysis: Fundamentals}
\noindent
\textbf{Essence:} \blindtext
% ////// [ PARAGRAPH END ]

\newpage
\rmfamily
\subsection{Mathematical Analysis: Differential Calculus}
\noindent
\textbf{Essence:} \blindtext
% ////// [ PARAGRAPH END ]

\newpage
\rmfamily
\subsection{Mathematical Analysis: Integral Calculus}
\noindent
\textbf{Essence:} \blindtext
% ////// [ PARAGRAPH END ]

\newpage
\rmfamily
\subsection{Mathematical Analysis: Series}
\noindent
\textbf{Essence:} \blindtext
% ////// [ PARAGRAPH END ]

\newpage
\rmfamily
\subsection{Mathematical Analysis: Differential Equations}
\noindent
\textbf{Essence:} \blindtext
% ////// [ PARAGRAPH END ]


\newpage
% section: Foundational Maths //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
\rmfamily
\section{Foundational Maths}
\subsection{Major: Minor}
\noindent
\textbf{Essence:} \blindtext
% ////// [ PARAGRAPH END ]


\newpage
% section: Stochastic Maths ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
\rmfamily
\section{Stochastic Maths}
\subsection{Major: Minor}
\noindent
\textbf{Essence:} \blindtext
% ////// [ PARAGRAPH END ]


\newpage
% section: Discrete Maths //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
\rmfamily
\section{Discrete Maths}
\subsection{Major: Minor}
\noindent
\textbf{Essence:} \blindtext
% ////// [ PARAGRAPH END ]

\endgroup
\end{document}
```